# BufferedWaveProvider converted for use in WaveMixerStream32 lowers pitch of audio

Tags: c#, naudio

I started working on a VOIP program to learn some of the basics of VOIP. I had it mostly working, but I ran into an issue after I converted my system over to use a WaveMixerStream32.

My program reads the input from a WaveIn using a 16 bit wave format, compresses it with the Speex codec, and sends it over the network where it is relayed to the client. At first, I had been using the BufferedWaveProvider incorrectly which caused me to look into using a WaveMixerStream32. However, to use this, I needed to convert the BufferedWaveProvider to a WaveStream32, which then can be used in a WaveMixerStream32.

The code I am using to convert is:

```
provider = new BufferedWaveProvider(format) { DiscardOnBufferOverflow = true };
wave16ToFloat = new Wave16ToFloatProvider(provider); // I have tried with and without this converter.
wpws = new WaveProviderToWaveStream(wave16ToFloat);
channel = new WaveChannel32(wpws);
```

I got the IWaveProvider to WaveStream converter from [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636142/wavemixerstream32-and-iwaveprovider).

I then add the final stream to a WaveMixerStream32 like this:

```
waveMixer.AddInputStream(channel);
```

Though it works much better than my original, the pitch over the final audio is significantly deeper than the input.

What am I doing wrong/How can I fix it?

Comment: If it sounds like "Luke, I am your father" then you got the bitrate wrong.  There is a factor of 2 in the sample size.

Comment: I found out it was related to this by messing with the sample rate, changed to 48kHz, only to find out that I then sounded like I had just inhaled a lot of helium. I had only changed the sample rate at the start because the codec that I was using, Speex, had a max sample rate setting of 32kHz. However, the sample rate that works turned out to be 44.1kHz.

Comment: It sounds to me like you have a much better answer than the one that you accepted.  Please don't be shy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

most likely you are playing stereo audio as though it were mono. That would halve the pitch. Check that the WaveFormat has the expected values in each point in the signal chain. Note that WaveChannel32 will be making mono into stereo.

Comment: Thanks, It turned out to be a combination of mono/stereo and mismatched sample rates.

Answer (score 2):

After following Mark and Hans' answers and tinkering with the sample rate, I have found that my WaveOutput was expecting a 44.1kHz sample rate, and I was only giving it 32kHz. I originally set my WaveIn sample rate to 32kHz as I expected my codec, Speex, to need that sample rate in order to function correctly (It's sample rate setting only goes as high as 32kHz). However, after changing the WaveIn sample rate to 44.1kHz, all the pitch issues have gone away.