# AcmNotPossible calling acmStreamOpen with WaveFormatConversionStream

Tags: c#, naudio

What I'm trying to do is convert a `WaveIn` microphone input to a different WaveFormat, and add that to a MixingSampleProvider.

```
        WaveIn waveIn = new WaveIn(this.Handle);
        waveIn.BufferMilliseconds = 25;
        waveIn.DataAvailable += waveIn_DataAvailable;

        // create wave provider
        WaveProvider waveProvider = new BufferedWaveProvider(waveIn.WaveFormat);
        WaveFormat commonWaveFormat = WaveFormat.CreateIeeeFloatWaveFormat(44100, 2);
        MixingSampleProvider msp = new MixingSampleProvider(commonWaveFormat);
        WaveFormatConversionStream wfcs = new WaveFormatConversionStream(commonWaveFormat,new WaveProviderToWaveStream(waveProvider));
        msp.AddMixerInput(wfcs);
        // create wave output to speakers
        waveOut = new WaveOut();
        waveOut.DesiredLatency = 100;
        waveOut.Init(msp);
```

where `WaveProviderToWaveStream` is a class from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636142/wavemixerstream32-and-iwaveprovider).
However, that gives me the following exception at `WaveFormatConversionStream`.

```
NAudio.MmException:AcmNotPossible calling acmStreamOpen
```

I tried

```
msp.addMixerInput(MediaFoundationResampler(waveProvider, commonWaveFormat).toSampleProvider());
```

which worked but produced a too large delay between talking into the microphone and hearing the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be much easier for you simply to specify the format you want to record in on the to `WaveIn` object itself.  (Just set the `WaveFormat` property before starting to record. It should still be 16 bit PCM, but specify the sample rate and channel count you want)

Then you can turn your `BufferedWaveProvider` into an `ISampleProvider` by using the `ToSampleProvider` extension method which will let you add it to the `MixingSampleProvider`

Comment: Thanks for your reply - thing is I want to mix my microphone input with a mp3 file read by a `MP3FileReader`. Since they don't share the same waveformat I need to convert them appropriatly.  Now I chose the given Format because it's the WaveFormat the mp3 files had in same examples. But I don't know for sure that `MP3FileReader` always returns the same WaveFormat, or does it always return the same for every possible mp3-file? If no, I'd still need to convert the mp3filereader.

Comment: additionally if `MP3FileReader` does return always the same WaveFormat I'd still have to adapt the mp3 waveformat since the Mixer only accepts IEEE-WaveFormats. Correct me if I'm wrong though

Comment: but the answer you provided solved the issue I presented in the question so I'll accept it - glad if you would still help me on the issue I wrote in the comments though ;)

Comment: Nevermind, I posted it as a new answer so it doesn't get out of hand: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33170763/resampling-mediafoundationreader-to-ieee-waveformat-fast