# NAudio - wave split and combine wave in realtime

Tags: c#, .net, naudio, mixing

I am working with a multi input soundcard and I want to achieve live mixing of multiple inputs. All the inputs are stereo, so I need to split them in first place, mix a selection of channel and provide them as mono stream.

The goal would be something like this mix Channel1[left] + Channel3[right] + Channel4[right] -> mono stream.

I have already implemented a process chain like this:

1) **WaveIn** -> create **BufferedWaveProvider** for each channel -> add Samples (just the ones for current channel) to each BufferedWaveProvider by using **wavein.DataAvailable += { buffwavprovider[channel].AddSamples(...)**...
This gives me a nice list of multiple BufferdWaveProvider. The splitting audio part here is implemented correctly.

2) Select multiple BufferedWaveProviders and give them to **MixingWaveProvider32**. Then create a WaveStream (using [WaveMixerStream32 and IWaveProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636142/wavemixerstream32-and-iwaveprovider)).

3) A MultiChannelToMonoStream takes that WaveStream and generates a mixdown. This also works.

But result is, that audio is chopped. Like some trouble with the buffer....

**Is this the correct way to handle this problem, or is there a way better solution around?**

edit - code added:

```
public class AudioSplitter
   {
      public List<NamedBufferedWaveProvider> WaveProviders { private set; get; }
      public string Name { private set; get; }
      private WaveIn _wavIn;
      private int bytes_per_sample = 4;

      /// <summary>
      /// Splits up one WaveIn into one BufferedWaveProvider for each channel
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="wavein"></param>
      /// <returns></returns>
      public AudioSplitter(WaveIn wavein, string name)
      {
         if (wavein.WaveFormat.Encoding != WaveFormatEncoding.IeeeFloat)
            throw new Exception("Format must be IEEE float");


         WaveProviders = new List<NamedBufferedWaveProvider>(wavein.WaveFormat.Channels);

         Name = name;
         _wavIn = wavein;
         _wavIn.StartRecording();
         var outFormat = NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat.CreateIeeeFloatWaveFormat(wavein.WaveFormat.SampleRate, 1);

         for (int i = 0; i < wavein.WaveFormat.Channels; i++)
         {
            WaveProviders.Add(new NamedBufferedWaveProvider(outFormat) { DiscardOnBufferOverflow = true, Name = Name + "_" + i });
         }

         bytes_per_sample = _wavIn.WaveFormat.BitsPerSample / 8;
         wavein.DataAvailable += Wavein_DataAvailable;
      }


      /// <summary>
      /// add samples for each channel to bufferedwaveprovider
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="sender"></param>
      /// <param name="e"></param>
      private void Wavein_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
      {
         int channel = 0;
         byte[] buffer = e.Buffer;
         for (int i = 0; i < e.BytesRecorded - bytes_per_sample; i = i + bytes_per_sample)
         {
            byte[] channel_buffer = new byte[bytes_per_sample];

            for (int j = 0; j < bytes_per_sample; j++)
            {
               channel_buffer[j] = buffer[i + j];
            }

            WaveProviders[channel].AddSamples(channel_buffer, 0, channel_buffer.Length);

            channel++;

            if (channel >= _wavIn.WaveFormat.Channels)
               channel = 0;

         }

      }
   }
```

Using the Audiosplitter for each channel gives a list of buffered wave provider (mono 32bit float).

```
 var mix = new MixingWaveProvider32(_waveProviders);
 var wps = new WaveProviderToWaveStream(mix);
 MultiChannelToMonoStream mms = new MultiChannelToMonoStream(wps);

 new Thread(() =>
  {
     byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

     while (mms.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) > 0 && isrunning)
     {


        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:\\temp\\audio\\mono_32.wav", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
        {
           fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }

     }
  }).Start();
```

Comment: Could you post code?

Comment: A few quick comments:  The outer loop in `DataAvailable should just run to "e.BytesRecorded".  Also, you don't need to reallocate "channel_buffer" each time through the loop (just do it once, outside the loop, and reuse it).

Comment: @BobC, thats exactly what I did yesterday and it way boosted the performance. Will provide my solution soon.

Answer (score 0):

there is some space left for optimization, but basically this gets the job done:

```
  private void Wavein_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
      {
         int channel = 0;
         byte[] buffer = e.Buffer;

         List<List<byte>> channelbuffers = new List<List<byte>>();
         for (int c = 0; c < _wavIn.WaveFormat.Channels; c++)
         {
            channelbuffers.Add(new List<byte>());
         }

         for (int i = 0; i < e.BytesRecorded; i++)
         {
            var byteList = channelbuffers[channel];

            byteList.Add(buffer[i]);

            if (i % bytes_per_sample == bytes_per_sample - 1)
               channel++;

            if (channel >= _wavIn.WaveFormat.Channels)
               channel = 0;
         }

         for (int j = 0; j < channelbuffers.Count; j++)
         {
            WaveProviders[j].AddSamples(channelbuffers[j].ToArray(), 0, channelbuffers[j].Count());
         }

      }
```

We need to provide a WaveProvider (WaveProviders[j]) for each channel.

Comment: Arno, did you solve the "audio is chopped" problem? I was thinking that the thread is reading the data much too fast.  There's no "brake" to make it wait for new samples to arrive, so the chain of Streams is probably returning 0's when "mms.Read()" is called and there's no new data.